# Java programming: classes in same packages

Tags: java, javac

I wrote two classes in java, f1 is compiling but f2 is not compiling and giving error f1 symbol not found.

**f1 class**

```
package x; 
public class f1 {  
    public void printf1() {  
        System.out.println("First Class"); 
    } 
}
```

The above class is compiling without error,

**f2 class**

```
package x;
public class f2 {

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        f1 f= new f1();
        f.printf1()
    }
}
```

How I can try javac -d or javaw for this code.

Comment: Place both `.java` files in a folder named `x`, then from the parent folder: Do `javac x/f2.java` to compile them both, and `java x.f2` to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here in your case both f1 and f2 ideally should be placed in the same directory, as they are of the same package.

f2 includes the main method. So to execute this program, you'd need compile f2.

If you do it like:

```
javac f2.java
```

This would give error `f1 symbol not found`, as f2 reference f1, and f1.class is not in the classpath.

So you could do:

```
javac f2.java f1.java
java f1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a semicolon to the end of this line:

```
f.printf1();
```

Your main method signature is correct. The name of String array does not matter .

Comment: That is true, i just wanted to answer like you

Comment: My question is how we import the classes in same packages

Comment: i saved both classes in my d drive 's x folder. but the second class i.e f2 is not reading the f1..

Comment: Create a directory under d drive i.e. test. Then cut and paste x directory under this new directory. Then run -javac command from this new directory. Not from x but test directory level.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep both of these classs under directory x. 
Then

Go to directory 'x' from command line/terminal

`cd x`

and then do

`javac f2.java`